# Results are missing while using the row number start and end indexes in oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, pagination, row-number

Following is the query to get the results from DB and there is scenario which fails the following query to get the number of results from the DB.

```
SELECT outer.*
FROM
(SELECT middle.*
FROM
(SELECT inner.*,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 2 ORDER BY 2 DESC) AS RN,
  COUNT(2) OVER()                                   AS COUNT
FROM
  (SELECT account.account_id,
    account.account_no
  FROM X account
  WHERE 1=1
  AND account.account_id NOT IN
    (SELECT account_tnx.account_id
    FROM A account_tnx
    WHERE account_tnx.tnx_stat_code IN (? ,? ,?,?,?,?)
    )
  AND ( account.product_type LIKE '%'  --'%IN'
  AND account.company_id= 10 )
  UNION
  SELECT account.account_id,
    account.account_no
  FROM A account
  LEFT JOIN U maker_user
  ON account.maker_id        = maker_user.user_id
  WHERE 1                    =1
  AND account.tnx_stat_code IN (?,?,?,?,?,?)
  AND ( account.product_type LIKE '%'   --'%IN'
  AND account.company_id= 10 )
  ) INNER
) middle
WHERE RN <= ? --(EndIndex)
) OUTER
WHERE outer.RN > ? --(StartIndex)
```

**A,X,U are tables in DB**

Case : There is an screen which contains search form with records per page (10/25/50/100) default is 50 records per page .
If i go to page default is 50 i will send start index as 0 and end index as 50 to java where it will set the start and end index and following is the scenario i am doing with search 1 and search 2

**Search 1 :-** Transaction Type:- Local Transfer & Status : New

(Retrieves the 2 records from the first 50 results in DB successfully out of total records 184 which will match my search with end index as 50).
Please refer image1 for this search

**Search 2 :-** Transaction Type:- *(Wildcard) & Status : New

(No records found when using wild card ( oracle like '%') means retrieving only first 50 records from DB out of 184 records (Because i am sending end index as 50 ) which will not match by search because 51 to 184 record is having my 2 records)
Please refer image2 for this search

There are no issues with query failure only need to get required records with out effecting the performance

My problem is while using wild cards it will retrieves more records when compared to transaction type filtering from query such that i am not able to retrieve the records using wild card search how to make it successful to get the required records from db

I am using the java jdbc

```
PrepareStatement  st = con.prepareStatement(query,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

I am using start and end index for performance related issues

Please provide a suggestion to get the records with following query changes without effecting my existing retrieval performance

or

Please provide some other option to improve my below query performance without indexes need to achieve the same performance

[image: Search 1]

[image: Search 2]

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 2 ORDER BY 2 DESC)` ... you realise you are effectively not partitioning or ordering anything there?

Comment: I am not that good at sql not sure about it might be using it for indexing the records

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` is an [analytic function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) that assigns a row number across a set of rows. The `PARTITION BY` clause determines the groups of rows you want to count across (e.g. across the whole set, or across a particular column or set of columns). If you use `PARTITION BY 2` you're effectively saying "assign a 2 to each row and now group the rows on that" - it's pointless, because you could achieve the same thing by missing out the `PARTITION BY` clause altogether.

Comment: Similar applies to the `ORDER BY` clause, only you need to have that when using `ROW_NUMBER()`, so what you're saying is "I don't care about the order the rows are numbered in". If that's what you're after, then fine, otherwise you'd need to specify the actual column(s) you wanted to order the results by. E.g. `row_number() over (order by account_no)`

Comment: Thanks for clarity on partition now i made changes on query by replacing partition by 2 to partition by transaction type now i am able to retrieve the records what am i doing is right ? I don't want to do any order by

Comment: If you're retrieving the correct rows following the change you made then yes, it sounds like that was the right thing to do.